# Get multiple network ports to work

Tags: networking, server

I have a 2 port NIC but for some reason Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS only sees one port, the first port queried, although both ports have valid devices connected. If I unplug the device from the port that works, then the other port works, but if I then reinsert the plug Ubuntu still sees only the second port. How can I get Ubuntu 18.04 to recognize both ports at the same time? Mythbuntu 16.04 did not have this problem; both ports worked fine all the time.

```
lshw -C network:
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82576 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0f0
       version: 01
       serial: 80:61:5f:08:33:7c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.2.1 ip=10.0.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:fe8e0000-fe8fffff memory:fe400000-fe7fffff ioport:dc00(size=32) memory:fe8dc000-fe8dffff memory:fe000000-fe3fffff memory:fe800000-fe81ffff memory:fe820000-fe83ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82576 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       logical name: enp2s0f1
       version: 01
       serial: 80:61:5f:08:33:7d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.2.1 ip=169.254.0.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:fe8a0000-fe8bffff memory:fdc00000-fdffffff ioport:d880(size=32) memory:fe8d8000-fe8dbfff memory:fd800000-fdbfffff memory:fe840000-fe85ffff memory:fe860000-fe87ffff

ip link show:
enp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:61:5f:08:33:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
enp2s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:61:5f:08:33:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Kernel: 5.4.0-65-generic x86-64

Comment: You could have provided details of your network hardware (`sudo lshw -C network` for example; which lists-hardware of class networking). I would also have provided details of the kernel in use; LTS releases have two kernel options, which is 4.15 if using GA for 18.04, and 5.4 if use HWE. Likewise for your 16.04 (4.4 for GA, 4.15 for HWE). The difference in kernels & kernel module (`driver=` of `lshw`) are where I'd first compare & look for clues.

Comment: It'll be difficult to answer this without knowing anything about the hardware. Can you update your question to include the output of `lshw -C network` and `ip link show`? This will make it easier for someone to offer specific advice 